# Invalid Credentials : for a normal user while ldap_simple_bind_s() function

Tags: objective-c, active-directory, ldap

I am using LDAP to authenticate the user.
I am doing ldap_simple_bind_s(ld,"CN=USERNAME,CN=Users,DC=domainname,DC=com");
In this call if passed USERNAME as domain user name ,query works fine. But if I passed normal user name or user who is part of the domain admin, I am getting INVALID CREDENTIALS error.
Please help me in resolving the issue.
Thanks,
Tausif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code described occurs when the password presented by the LDAP client does not match the password stored in the directory for the distinguished name presented in the simple BIND request. Be aware that many directory servers also return the code for invalid credentials when the distinguished name does not exist, and in other cases - this prevents attackers from knowing that an entry does or does not exist.

Comment: Hi Terry, Yes I have checked the password. I am having one test domain where I have created few users. The same issue is seen for these users whereas administrator is able to bind without any issue. So what other things may I check to resolve this issue.Thanks, Tausif.